# How to render data from multiple models django

Tags: python, django

I want to render data to my webpage from my django app however only two of the required slots are being rendered

my models are:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True , blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True)
    points = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=0, null=True)
```

and my views are

```
def admin_dashboard (request):
        
            order_list = Order.objects.all()

            context = {'order':order_list}

            template = "admin_dashboard.html"
            return render(request, 'store/admin_dashboard.html', context)
```

my HTML is:

```
{% extends 'store/admin_main.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}
{% for order in order %}

<h6>{{ order.transaction_id }}</h6>
<p>{{ order.customer }}</p>
<p>{{ order.shippingaddress }}</p> 
<p>{{ order.orderitem }}</p>  

{% endfor%}
{% endblock content %}
```

1598061443.212917
userNew

which is just the transaction id and user.

how can I have all the rest of fields filled

Comment: What is `ordersinfo`? And `{% for order in order %}` does not seem to be a good idea?

Comment: My bad it should be order_list

Comment: You can get the OrderItem**s** related with `order.orderitem_set`. But there is no shipping address anywhere in the models.